# R how to create a column that aggregates multiple conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi I'm looking to filter my dataframe in R and aggregate the multiple conditions of a person (ID).
How can I do this after using groupby?

Df:

```
ID  | Condition

S123| D 
S123| H
S123| D,L

S456| L
S456| L,D
S456| L

S789| D
S789| L
S789| D
```

Result needed:

```
ID  | Condition

S123| D,H,L 
S456| L,D
S789| D,L
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bring the comma-separated values into different rows and then paste `unique` `Conditions` for each `ID`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(Condition, sep = ",") %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(Condition = toString(unique(Condition)))

#  ID    Condition
#  <fct> <chr>    
#1 S123  D, H, L  
#2 S456  L, D     
#3 S789  D, L
```

---

In base R, we can use `aggregate` with `strsplit` to split the strings on comma.

```
aggregate(Condition~ID, df, function(x) toString(unique(unlist(strsplit(x, ",")))))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), .Label = c("S123", "S456", "S789"), class = "factor"), Condition = c("D", 
"H", "D,L", "L", "L,D", "L", "D", "L", "D")), row.names = c(NA,-9L), 
class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, it seems to work well, except that for those rows where Conditions has missing values, I'm getting results like D, ,H,L or , H, L etc. any suggestions to tidy up?

Comment: @spidermarn just wrap it in `na.omit`, like `toString(unique(na.omit(Condition))))` and I think for base R, it should work as it is.